# How to change to lowercase every tags in xml file with awk or sed on Unix AIX 7.2?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, aix

I need to convert all the tags in an XML file to lowercase on Unix AIX 7.2. I`m trying to make it with awk.

I'm trying to convert to lowercase every tag found with the regex /(\<[^>]*>)/

I've tried using sed, but \L and \U do not exist in sed AIX 7.2.
I've tried with awk gsub,
it seems the entire line is in $0 if I try to print it.

I've made a piece of code if it matches a tag, it will print `tolower` else only print.

However, I would need a way to cut the text.

```
    awk '{
        gsub(/(\<[^>]*\>)/,"&"); 
        if(match($0,/(\<[^>]*\>)/)) 
            print tolower($1); 
        else 
            print $0;
        };' test.xml
```

this is the input :

```
<Record> BLAHBLAHBLAH <Record>
</RRecord> CapCapCapcaps <RRecord>
```

I'm trying to get :

```
<record> BLAHBLAHBLAH <record>
</rrecord> CapCapCapcaps <rrecord>
```

instead im getting :

```
<record> blahblahblah <record>
</rrecord> capcapcapcaps <rrecord>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: What do you mean with "tags"?

Comment: What do you mean with tag. You also give an example output and what you get, but you do not give us an example input. (also the output is not valid xml)

Comment: Sorry, by "tags" i mean that's between <>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not the way you're thinking. Not really. XML is not a Regular Language. That is a technical term, "Regular".

To do this the right way, you need a XML parser. Parse the document, emit the same thing back out. Now add a bit of code that changes the node name to different case.

This should be about 10 lines of Python or Perl, and it'd work perfectly, not halfway like a RegEx would do.